# Understanding javax.inject example code?

Tags: java, spring

I would very much appreciate someone helping me understand this javax example code and why the @inject annotation is actually useful/what it does. The code below comes from:
[Code From this Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html)

```
class Stopwatch {
 final TimeSource timeSource;
 @Inject Stopwatch(TimeSource TimeSource) {
   this.TimeSource = TimeSource;
 }
 void start() { ... }
 long stop() { ... }
}
```

First off, I think (I hope) there is a typo and the "TimeSource" parameter should really be "timeSource", since the field in the Stopwatch class is CamelCase.

What I really don't understand though is what the @inject annotation is actually doing!? Is it equivalent to this constructor?:

```
class Stopwatch {
 final TimeSource timeSource;
 Stopwatch(TimeSource timeSource) {
 this.timeSource = timeSource;
 }
}
```

Above is how I would handle adding the dependency, so I hope I'm correct that's how the @inject keyword does it... Or am I way off??

Comment: Have you read the JavaDocs to this annotation, as it is briefly described for what purpose `@Inject` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have understood Spring's `@Autowired` annotation then, the code above is no different.`@Autowired` is a Spring specific annotation and `@Inject` comes from the Java Dependency Injection specification

```
class Stopwatch {
 final TimeSource timeSource;
 @Inject Stopwatch(TimeSource TimeSource) {
   this.TimeSource = TimeSource;
 }
 void start() { ... }
 long stop() { ... }
}
```

Here, `@Inject` is indicating that when the instance of `Stopwatch` is created, it should be instantiated via that constructor and pass in an instance that is assignable to `TimeSource`

> Instead of the programmer calling a constructor or factory, a tool
>   called a dependency injector passes dependencies to objects

So, as stated here, the dependency injector will make sure to inject an instance of `TimeSource` while creating an instance of `Stopwatch`.

Comment: TWIST: If you have not understood Spring's @Autowired annotation then, go through this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K43qyHJXmWI ... Come back and you will understand what this answer means!!

Answer (score 4):

Late answer but may help someone else.
The @Inject annotation does nothing on its own.

You need a framework that will act on the annotation.

e.g. Guice

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
YourObject yo = injector.getInstance(YourObject.class);
```

The annotation is in javax to provide a standard name, so in theory I could swap Guice for something else.